# Time scale in survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am doing a churn analysis of some bank customers with survival analysis.

Right now I am using the customers' years in the bank [0;17] as time scale, and then use the customers' entry age as a covariate in Cox proportional hazard model. But this model doesn't give me an answer, because I can't find a proportional hazard model. 
So I thought about changing the time scale to the customers' age [0;100] instead of the customers' years in the bank. And when I do that, it is possible to find a proportional hazard model, that meets the assumption.

But when a do that I get a different median survival time. Is that correct? I should not get the same Kaplan Meier estimate, when I use a different time scale, shouldn't I?

Comment: Could you state your question and why the original analysis doesn't seem to give you an answer? It seems to be straight forward for analysis. The alternative of 0 - 100 years leaves you with entry at any age and departure at any older age. I don't see how this would be helpful.

Comment: When I use the customers' years in the bank time scale I can't find a proportional model, but then I use age as a time scale it is possible for me to find a proportionale model

Comment: What is the question though? E.g. analyzing the age of customers rather than how long they stay customers for, may not be very helpful, if you want to find out factors that predict customer non-retention... Not every time-to-event model has to be a proportional hazards model, it might well be that the best model to do what you want is not going to be one.